# which linq to use to get collection searching in the collection inside current collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dbcontext

in my database I have Table `Courses`, each course contains List of `Faculties`.

With LINQ I need to get all courses that have a faculty with specified faculty id.

I am trying to do something like that:

```
        var courses = dc.Courses.Include("ClassTimes").Where(course => course.Facultys.Where(fac => fac.Id == currentFacultyId));
```

but it doesn't work... I am pretty sure there should be another LINQ api that created for this purpose, I just need someone to point me.

Thank you

Comment: are you using the ADO.NET Data Model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.Any()` to achieve that :

```
var courses = dc.Courses
                .Include("ClassTimes")
                .Where(course => course.Facultys.Any(fac => fac.Id == currentFacultyId));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.Contains()`:

```
var courses = dc.Courses.Include("ClassTimes").Where(course => course.Facultys.Contains(fac => fac.Id == currentFacultyId));
```

**Explanation:**

`Contains` will solve this problem, since the `Where` expression expects to return a boolean answer for every item in the collection.

`Where` - return items that match the given condition.

`Contains` - returns boolean whether the collection contains an item that matches the given condition.